# python-requests: Limit Number of Redirects Followed

Tags: python, python-requests

Is there a way to limit the number of redirects that python-requests will follow when performing a GET?

[I know about](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.request) `allow_redirects=False`, but that just prevents redirects all together.  I'm looking for a way to follow redirects, up to some maximum number of hops.

```
# What I know how to do:
resp = requests.get(url)  # follows redirects "infinitely"
resp = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)  # follows no redirects

# What I'm trying to do:
resp = requests.get(url, max_redirects=3)  # follow up to 3 redirects
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have to create [`Session`](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Session) object and set `max_redirects` variable to 3

```
session = requests.Session()
session.max_redirects = 3
session.get(url)
```

`TooManyRedirects` exception will be raised if a requests exceeds maximum number of redirects.

Related github issue discussing why you can not set `max_redirects` per request https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/1300

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get the header (or other information) of the request that cause the Max Rediect Limit Exception, you can do like that:

```
session = requests.Session()
session.max_redirects = 1
try:
    r = session.post(url, headers=headers, params=querystring, data=payload)
except requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects as exc:
    r = exc.response
```

Make sure your requests are the latest edition.