# locust limit number redirects followed

Tags: python, redirect, python-requests, locust

I'm playing with Locust and I need to limit the number of redirects. In my case the URL has 4 redirects (302, 303) so I try with:

```
    session = requests.Session()
    session.max_redirects = 2
    try:
        response = self.client.post(self.url,
                                    headers=headers,
                                    name='name',
                                    params=params,
                                    data=data)
        for i in response.history:
            print(i.url)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.info('Error on get_request_url request: %s', e)
        sys.exit(1)
```

But this does not limit the redirects, any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "is not working"?

Comment: In this case the redirects continue at the end, 4 redirects in my case. So i'm not able to control the number of redirects in locust

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31552627/python-requests-limit-number-of-redirects-followed

Comment: you are creating a requests.Session but then you never use your session.